# RoR rjs assign prompt value to variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

how i can assign rjs prompt value to a variable

page << "prompt('Enter the new first name:');"

when i call in alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just adding your assignment to your javascript statement:

```
page << "var response = prompt('Enter the new first name:');"
```

You should then be able to access the value of `response` in your client side javascripts.